# Copying custom json object to clipboard with javascript

Tags: javascript, android, json, html, canvas

I'm developing a shared canvas using HTML5 + javascript. I am developing copying/pasting functionality, and I have no problems to do it with Ctrl+C, +X, +V, but I also would like to add the typical buttons that provide the same functionality (mainly intended to be able to copy/paste in tablets).

The code to manage the standard events is quite straigtforward:

```
window.addEventListener("copy", copyFunc);

...

copyFunc(e){
  if (BDKanvasInstance.selection !== null){
    var data = BDKanvasInstance.selection.serialize();
    var jsonData = JSON.stringify(data);
    e.clipboardData.setData('application/json', jsonData);
    e.preventDefault();
  }
}
```

But I have to way to access the clipboardData from a button...

```
copyBtn.addEventListener("click", copyBtnFunc);

copyBtnFunc(e){
  /* Any way to access clipboardData or to trigger the standard copy command? */
}
```

I've seen several solutions involving creating a textarea, inserting the text, selecting it programmatically and using "execCommand('copy')", but that does not copy the text with an "application/json" type...

Any solutions? With a computer using keyboard shortcuts is ok, but they are not a solution when using it on the tablet...

Thank you!

Comment: To be able to modify clipboard data without an initial "copy" event from the user, you need Flash ([This plugin](http://zeroclipboard.org/) does a really good job at it). But iOS does not have Flash. Are you only targeting Android devices?

Comment: I am targeting any HTML5 browser... that's why I do not want to use Flash, because it is not cross platform. Thank you!

Comment: Ok, then, I don't think you can do this without Flash (I've done a lot of research on this in the past). Do you intend to copy **and** paste on the same website? If so, you could use a cookie or localstorage as a backup plan (ie: When you hit the "copy" button, store the value you want in a cookie, and later, when you hit another "paste" button, insert the data from the cookie wherever you want.)

Comment: Yes, if it all happens on the same page, you can use a simple JS variable as you did (the cookie method is only relevant if you want to copy data across multiple pages).

Answer (score 2):

Everything is done on the same page, so I've done:

```
window.addEventListener("copy", copyFunc);

...

copyFunc(e){
  if (BDKanvasInstance.selection !== null){
    var data = BDKanvasInstance.selection.serialize();
    if (e && e.clipboardData)
    {
      var jsonData = JSON.stringify(data);
      e.clipboardData.setData('application/json', jsonData);
      e.preventDefault();
    } else {
      internalClipboard = data;
    }
  }
}

copyBtn.addEventListener("click", copyBtnFunc);

copyBtnFunc(e){
  copyFunc(null);
}
```

And similar with the three actions (copy/cut/paste). The buttons call the functions from their handlers, with a null argument. There is a "clipboard" for the buttons, and another one for the shortcuts. Dirty, but may do the trick...

Thank you!